# Configuring storage options in social engine

Tags: local-storage, socialengine

I installed social engine successfully.

Everything was working fine, until there was a need to change the social engine's default storage location.

From admin side there is an option to change the storage service. I want to retain the current local storage service, but make a path different from 'public' folder (which is default).

But even after changing the path, all the modules make their uploads to public folder itself.

Can any one help in configuring that?

Answer (score 0):

I think, public folder will be default for all existing modules and for all newly installed modules. My suggested solution is to create a symbolic link folder instead of public if it is possible in your situation.